# Count - Идентификатор

Tags: c++

Пишет, что count - необъявленный идентификатор...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    count << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Оператор вывода на консоль cout, а не count! Минус не ставлю из доброты душевной.

Comment: Был же уже такой вопрос где-то...

Comment: lol что???  
правильно писать cout \<\< "Hello, world!;

Comment: И откуда только берутся такие тупые вопросы? Что, нельзя было в книгу посмотреть, как там "Hello, World!" сделан?

>Оператор вывода на консоль cout, а не count! Минус не ставлю из доброты душевной.

 А, может, ты просто очко уважения, как я, пожалел?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. не count, а cout
2. или после инклюдов написать using namespace std; или писать std::cout

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, вместо `count` должно быть `std::cout`.

Answer (score -1):

не промолчу!!! count должен быть переменной, а для вывода должно быть написано cout << endl;

Comment: должен Вам сказать, что cout - тоже переменная.

Comment: объект!!!!

Comment: Не зразумив.

Comment: раз С++ это ООП, то cout -- объект. иногда я еще встречал название "поток", но переменная -- ниразу.

Comment: Переменная - это грубо говоря имя некой области памяти, которая имеет какую-то структуру и что-то содержит в себе. Благодаря этому имени происходит доступ к этой области. Объект - это некая физическая реальность в памяти, а доступ к ней осуществляется благодаря переменной, которая имеет тип этой области памяти, в данной случае абстрактный тип,т.е. класс.